# Julia DataFrams: How to get the max array column in DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, julia

Simple but unresolved this.:-<

I simply wanna get the max data in DataFrame.

1. findmax(df.B) returns the total row number, in the case of below '7'.
   I expected it returned '3' in row=5,6,7, what does return them?
2. findmax(df.C) returns the first 'max' data, in the case of below (6.0,5).
   But others, (6.0,6) and (6.0,7)?

Hope you give me a hint.

```
   row      A            B              C
│      |  String       Array…         Float64
│ ─────┼─────────────────────────────────────────
│    1 │ ftest2.id    [4, 5]                 4.0
│    2 │ ftest3.name  [4, 5]                 4.0
│    3 │ ftest2.id    [4]                    5.0
│    4 │ ftest3.id    [5]                    4.0
│    5 │ ftest.sex    [3, 4, 5]              6.0
│    6 │ ftest2.id    [3, 4, 5]              6.0
└    7 │ ftest3.name  [3, 4, 5]              6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

For `df.C`, you can do:

```
julia> findall(==(maximum(df.C)), df.C)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 5
 6
 7
```

This returns all the row numbers that have the maximum value for that column

For `df.B`, it's not clear what your expectation of "max data" is for that column. As it is, `findmax(df.B)` returns `([5], 4)`, which is the way arrays are usually compared in Julia (`5` is larger than all the other first elements of the inner arrays). Do you wish to find the rows with the maximum length array in them? For that, you can do:

```
julia> B_len = length.(df.B)
       findall(==(maximum(B_len)), B_len)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 5
 6
 7
```

Comment: Thank you Sundar R. Yes, that's perfect answer. 
Just wanna correct this for others.
B_len = length.(df.B)

Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed that in the answer.